# Retrieving information from a different page in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I need to list bullfighters who have a spouse who sings couplet. I've the following example:
Francisco Rivera (http://es.dbpedia.org/page/resource/Francisco_Rivera) was a bullfighter who was married to a couplet Singer called Isabel Pantoja (http://es.dbpedia.org/page/resource/Isabel_Pantoja)
How do I retrieve information from Isabel when I'm using Francisco's page as main.

From http://es.dbpedia.org/page/resource/Francisco_Rivera I can identify:
1. His bullfighter occupation in dbpedia-owl:occupation
2. His spouse in dbpedia-owl:spouse
From http://es.dbpedia.org/page/resource/Isabel_Pantoja I can identify:
1. Her genre to be couplet (coplas) in dcterms:subject

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

SELECT distinct ?bullfighter ?spousename where {
?bullfighter
   foaf:name ?bullfighter;
   dbpedia-owl:occupation <http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Torero>.
?spouse
   dbpedia-owl:spouse <http://es.dbpedia.org/page/resource/Isabel_Pantoja>;
   foaf:name ?spousename;
   dct:subject ?subject.
FILTER (contains (str(?subject), "copla")).
}
```

I expect, at least, the bullfighter: Francisco Rivera and his spouse name: Isabel Pantoja

Comment: what is that for a URI: `http://es.dbpedia.org/page/resource/Isabel_Pantoja`? `/page/resource/` ? It's always just `/resource/` in DBpedia.

Comment: and where is the triple pattern that "connects" the bullfighter with his spouse?

Comment: `PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

SELECT distinct ?bullfighter  ?spousename where {
?s <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/occupation> <http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Torero> ; 
foaf:name ?bullfighter ;
dbo:spouse ?spouse .
?spouse foaf:name ?spousename ;
dct:subject ?subject .
FILTER (contains (str(?subject), "copla"))
}`

Comment: The page `http://es.dbpedia.org/page/Francisco_Rivera` describes the entity `http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Francisco_Rivera`.  As @AKSW suggested, ``http://es.dbpedia.org/page/resource/Francisco_Rivera` does not exist, nor does any other DBpedia URI containing `page/resource`.